# Error message will not display after changing the type for a button in form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

So I am trying to add validation to a form. Initially, for the button, I had the type as submit, but when I would click on the button the error message for an empty name input would display briefly. I did some research and saw that in order to get the error message to display longer, I needed to change the type to button, which I did.  Now, no error messages are showing. I checked the console and there are no errors displaying.  Can someone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

```js
function printError(elemId, message) {
  document.getElementById(elemId).innerHTML = message;
}

function validateForm() {
  var name = document.regForm.FullName.value;

  var nameError = true;
  if (name == "") {
    printError("nameError", "Please enter your name")
  }
};
```

```css
.error {
    color: red;
    font-size: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form name="regForm" class="form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="row">
        <label>Full Name</label></br>
        <input name="FullName" type="text" placeholder="John Doe" id="FullName" />
        <div class="error" id="nameError"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label>Email</label></br>
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="johndoe@email.com" id="Email" />
        <div class="error" id="emailError"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label>Phone Number</label></br>
        <input name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="(123) 456-7890" id="PhoneNumber" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label>Password</label></br>
        <input name="Password" id="Password" type="Password" placeholder="Password" onchange='passConfirm();' />
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label>Confirm Password</label></br>
        <input name="ConfirmPassword" id="ConfirmPassword" type="Password" placeholder="Confirm Password" onchange='passConfirm();' />
      </div>
      <span id="Message"></span>
      <button type="button" value="submit">Sign Me Up!</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The console is not the DOM. You need to `throw new Error('message here');` or the like, to get the error to show in the console. Usually, you just use `Error`s for testing purposes, as the Client probably won't be looking for them.

Answer (score 0):

When the button type is `submit` the form gets submitted automatically and the `function` called `validation` is executed. But when you change the `type` to button the function will not be called. You have to add `click` event listener to the *sign me up* button to call the validate function.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ur7sgya2/)